# How do I update a dataframe column that includes numbers and letters to shorten the value?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a set of data that relates to quarters, like this:

```
Date     Value
1997Q1    1
1997Q2    2
1997Q3    3
1997Q4    4
1998Q1    5
1998Q2    6
1998Q3    7
1998Q4    8
```

I want to convert the 'Date' column into a 'year' column, where the Q's have been removed and I'm left with only the year. So basically, I want to trim the last 2 digits on the end of all values in my 'Date' column.

```
Year    Value
1997    1
1997    2
1997    3
1997    4
1998    5
1998    6
1998    7
1998    8
```

I tried this:

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].apply(lambda x: x[:4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this approach:

Just get the year from the Date column

```
df['Year'] = df['Date'].str[:4]
```

And then drop the Date column if you don't want that further.

```
df.drop(columns=['Date'], inplace=True)
```

Also, added output for reference,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a column that doesn't exist.

```py
df['Year'].apply(lambda x: x[:4])
```

This throws an error because there is no 'Year' column, yet.

Replace with the actual Date column

```py
df['Year'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x[:4])
```

then, you could drop the Date column if you no longer want it

```py
df.drop('Date', axis=1, inplace=True)
```